# Convert to string from an array of characters

Tags: c++

I would like to convert an array of characters to a wide string like this

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring ws=converter.from_bytes({99,108,105,235,110,116}).
```

But this doesn't work.

```
`235` is an invalid narrowing conversion from int to char:constant character doesn't fit in destination type.
```

Comment: What are the signs that it does not work?

Comment: The error message is saying, in a weird way, that on your compiler the `char` type is *signed*, and `235` is beyond the range of a signed 8-bit integer (which is -128 to 127).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only arguably viable overload of `from_bytes` for your code is the version taking a `const byte_string&`. You aren't using a custom allocator, so `byte_string` is `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`, a.k.a. `std::string`.

`std::string` has an `initalizer_list<char>` constructor; however, `char` on your platform is signed, and cannot represent the value `235`, making the implicit conversion from `235` to `char` a narrowing conversion, which is not allowed at the top level of a braced initializer list.

Use `char(235)` instead to explicitly convert it to a `char`.

Comment: But I still get an error for bad conversion, 235 can't be converted to wide

Comment: @MikhailLucas Then your source array is not valid UTF-8.